# Error en source(): bidi formatting. R, Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy teniendo la siguiente situación:

Tengo unos archivos ".R" guardados en un directorio en los que estoy almacenando ciertas bases de datos. En general, para recuperar dichas bases, sólo hago un:

```
# traer el archivo con:
base <- source("nombredelarchivo.R") 

#Extraer la parte que me interesa con:
base2 <- base$value
```

Esto lo vengo haciendo en una distro Debian con la que habitualmente trabajo y funciona sin problemas. Hace pocos días comenzamos un proceso de migración hacia Linux Mint y al tratar de traer el mismo archivo, con el mismo código, ejecutando incluso el mismo script en la carpeta compartida en la que se encuentra, comienza a arrojar el siguiente error:

**Error in source("bases/nombredelarchivo.R") :**

**bidi formatting not allowed (line 3823), use escapes instead (\u2066)**

Esto sucede con los archivos que fueron creados corriendo el script en la Distribución Debian, pero con los archivos que he creado recientemente usando linux MINT, a través del mismo código, no se presenta el error???

El código para crear el archivo .R es:

```
dump(c("base"), file= "bases/nombredelarchivo.R")
```

Quizás vale mencionar que cuando pongo a funcionar el script en la Distribución Debian, funciona sin problemas, incluso logro recuperar las bases que he creado usando Linux MINT. El problema está en el inverso, cuando desde Mint, trato de recuperar los .R que creé usando Debian

Una solucuón sencilla sería seguir usando Debian, pero la migración va en firme y, a pesar de que no consigo solución, no debería ser tan complicado resolverlo, verdad?

Lo que he logrado leer por ahí con casos similares es un problema con la codificación del idioma, pero no logra solucionar.

Si alguién tiene una idea o puede sugerir por dónde podría conseguir información útil le agradecería un montón.

Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La bidireccionalidad de lectura es algo implementado en el estándar Unicode, es decir podemos combinar palabras en castellano (LTR) junto con texto en hebreo (RTL), pero a nivel de código esto puede representar un problema difícil de manejar (de hecho hay pruebas de concepto de ataques maliciosos usando la bidireccionalidad de cadenas). Por defecto R no permite la bidireccionalidad del código, es decir todo el texto se interpreta en una única dirección, el error se debe a que en el script generado se han encontrado caracteres que "cambian" la dirección de lectura, el "culpable" hay que buscarlo, por ejemplo en el objeto `base`, seguramente en él hay alguna cadena con algún código de cambio de dirección, que es válida tal vez como parte de estos datos, pero al hacer un `dump()` el dato se transforma en código R que ya no permite este tipo de caracteres.

La solución paliativa es "buscar" este carácter no permitido en el código y modificarlo por la secuencia de escape literal del mismo, que el mensaje de error ya te lo menciona [`\u2066`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2066/index.htm)

Comment: Gracias Patricio por tus siempre pertinentes comentarios. Me parece que tu planteamiento es bastante sólido y trataré de buscar ese carácter (aunque la base tiene algo así como 65 columnas y me parece que será un procedimiento algo tedioso). Me sigue quedando la duda de porque al correr el script en Rstudio desde la distribución Debian no da ningún error y carga la información sin problemas?

Comment: ¿Los datos son exactamente los mismos? por que en principio, según mi hipótesis no debería ser una cuestión del sistema operativo., sino más bien de los datos. ¿Tenés forma de compartir los datos? los podría revisar eventualmente. Saludos.

Comment: Los datos son exactamente los mismos. De hecho están en un mismo disco duro que tiene doble boot (Debian y Linux Mint). AL abrir con Debian, todo se lee, al abrir con MInt, sólo se leen los que bajé usando el script en MINT

Comment: Es muy extraño, yo si tuviera el mismo problema, generaría el script en ambos ambientes y los compararía con un diff visual, eso tal vez aporte algún dato mas.